# Is null condition needed if stricttype=1 declared?

Tags: php, null, arguments, php-7.4

I have class method in PHP, declared strict types and it's first argument is XMLWriter (should generate XML). I wonder if I need to check null condition on it, or PHP interpret checks even null pointer? I did it everytime before, but is it needed with PHP7 and strict types?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your class definition please? I depends if you use `XmlWriter $writer` or `?XmlWriter $xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you typehint an argument as `XMLWriter`, then it's impossible to pass `NULL` to that method. PHP 7's `strict_types` declaration doesn't affect this behavior.

```php
<?php

class Example
{
    function foo(XMLWriter $writer)
    {}
}

$object = new Example();
$object->foo(null); // TypeError in PHP 7+, fatal error in older versions
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is null condition needed if stricttype=1 declared?

[According to the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict)

> By default, 
>   PHP will coerce values of the wrong type into the
>   expected **scalar** type if possible. For example, a function that is
>   given an integer for a parameter that expects a string will get a
>   variable of type string.

*Strict typing is only defined for **scalar type** declarations, objects are **compound types**.*

So you don't need to worry about objects internally. However, you need to worry about objects non-internally and ask yourself:

**Can this parameter be NULL ?**

If yes, then you need to check the parameter's nullability (`$writer` in this case)

---

There are three different ways to handle nullable data types:

**1- Set the default value of the parameter to NULL**

```
function foo(XMLWriter $writer = null) ...
```

Then check within the method if `$writer` is null.

---

**2- Add a leading question mark symbol to the parameter data type (PHP +7.1)**

```
function foo (?XMLWriter $writer) ...
```

> **Note:** unlike (method 1) the parameter here does not have a default value

---

**3- Catch the `TypeError` exception (PHP +7)**

```
class A {
    public function foo (XMLWriter $writer) {
    }
}

$a = new A;

try {
    $a->foo(null);
} catch (TypeError $e) {
    // Error handling
}
```